# How to specify commandline arguments in pgrep in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, process, grep

I have few processes running with same name but different commandline arguments.

```
$ ps -ef | grep process_name 
myusername 19276 6408 0 18:12 pts/22 00.00.00 process_name 4010 127.0.0.1
myusername 23242 6369 0 18:32 pts/11 00.00.00 process_name 4010 127.0.0.2
```

How can I get the process id based on the full name of the process e.g. `process_name 4010 127.0.0.1`?

I tried using `pgrep`, but it looks like this does not look into arguments.

```
$ pid=$(pgrep process_name) 
19276 23242
$ pid=$(pgrep process_name 4010 127.0.0.1) #error
$ pid=$(pgrep "process_name 4010 127.0.0.1") #blank
$ pid=$(pgrep "process_name\s4010\s127.0.0.1") #blank
$ pid=$(pgrep "process_name[[:space:]]4010[[:space:]]127.0.0.1") #blank
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `-f` option to match against full command line:

```
pgrep -f 'process_name 4010 127.0.0.1'
```

This will also match `subprocess_name 4010 127.0.0.11`.  If you want to avoid that, use `^` to anchor the match at the beginning and `$` as an anchor at the end:

```
pgrep -f '^process_name 4010 127.0.0.1$'
```

#### Documentation

From `man pgrep`:

> -f, --full
>   The pattern is normally only matched against the process
>   name.   When  -f  is set, the full command line is used.